# Creating object using modal in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I'm trying to add an object to my database using a modal (from materialize). When the user clicks the "new" button, the modal will be displayed and after filling out the form, the object will be created.

The main view looks like this

```
.
.
.
<%= link_to "add", new_item_path, remote: true %>
.
. 
.
<div id="addItemModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 class="col s12">Add Item</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <%= form_with(model: Item.new, class: "col s12") do |f| %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "validate" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-
         green btn-flat">Cancel</a>
    <%= button_to "Save",
        items_path,
        class: "modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn 
        light-blue darken-2 text-white", remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user fills out the modal form and clicks submit, the create action is called in the items_controller

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.js
    else
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I took a look at the params hash after submission and it appears the values entered into the form are not being sent to the create action. Ive checked the input fields and they seem to be connected to the object

```
<input class="validate" type="text" name="item[name]">
```

Edit:

Server Response

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-26 17:59:23 -0500
Processing by ItemsController#create as JS
Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"B1YVBtBy0NGe0jnhdeJquj19g8aJa8WfNwA/k8vekOySACiJ20wnR5XAI2rw7mIIUSnp5K7ZqmLxYdddGqimvw=="}
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/?message=Error+Saving
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: do you mind pasting what you get in the rails console when you click on Submit ?.

Comment: I've updated my question with the server response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `submit` button to the form, your current button creates a form of its own with no data.

Try chaning `button_to` to `f.submit` and be sure to include it inside the `form_with` block:

```
<div id="addItemModal" class="modal">
  <%= form_with(model: Item.new, class: "col s12") do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="col s12">Add Item</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "validate" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cancel</a>
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn light-blue darken-2 text-white" %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```